# Force uiscrollview to bounce scrolling even with a single item

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView with varying numbers of items/subviews. When there is more than one item, scrolling bounce works. However, there are times when the scrollview should only have one item, and I would like to provide the feedback to the user that their scrolls are being recognized--thus the bounce effect. However, UIScrollView disables scrolling with just one item.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Answer: set alwaysBounceHorizontal or alwaysBounceVertical to true. I answered my own question while writing this up and figured I might as well post it to help others.

Comment: @clifgriffin: He won't be able to do it for another 48 hours since it's a self-answer. But good reminder nevertheless.

Comment: Ah yes, forgot about that restriction.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, a UIScrollView will not scroll in (width / height) if the contentSize property is not greater than the frame property (in width / height)