# Force phonegap/cordova app to bounce when scrolling even with a single item

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, iscroll

This question is similar to this one: [Force uiscrollview to bounce scrolling even with a single item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5021338/force-uiscrollview-to-bounce-scrolling-even-with-a-single-item) but the answer didn't solve my problem as I am using cordova, HTML 5 and Javascript to build my app.

My app uses iScroll to implement bounce effect on scrolling but it is not bouncing when the content fits the whole screen; it is not having the bounce effect when there is no need to scroll.

Help? Thanks!

Comment: as far as I know, it isn't possible with iscroll

Comment: Do you know anything that I can do it with? or any tricks to achieve the bounce effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't seem to find an alternative that lets me do this so I modified the core iscroll.js (v5.1.1) and added my own code inside `iScroll.prototype.refresh`:

```
this.hasHorizontalScroll    = this.options.scrollX && this.maxScrollX < 0;
this.hasVerticalScroll      = this.options.scrollY && this.maxScrollY < 0;

//---- my code starts here
// set default value to 0 if the maxscrolly is greater than 0
//and set hasVerticalScroll to true (always true)
  this.maxScrollY = (this.maxScrollY > 0) ? 0) : this.maxScrollY;
  this.hasVerticalScroll = true;
//---- my code ends here

if ( !this.hasHorizontalScroll ) {
        this.maxScrollX = 0;
        this.scrollerWidth = this.wrapperWidth;
    }

if ( !this.hasVerticalScroll ) {
        this.maxScrollY = 0;
        this.scrollerHeight = this.wrapperHeight;
}
```

**this will enable the scroll bounce effect even if the page has no content.*